# Evenly distribute number into array of n elements with equal values

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to divide `x` into `y` parts and they should be as evenly distributed as possible.

As an example:
if `x = 5` and `y = 3` I'd like to have `arr = [1, 2, 2]`.

The solution I came up with basically prints [1, 1, 3] which isn't as evenly as possible distributed.

```
int *arr= (int *)malloc(y* sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = x / y;

        if (i == nrThreads - 1)
        {
            arr[i] = x / y+ x % y;
        }
        
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
```

The order of the array entries does not matter. It can be either of the three:
 `[1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1]`

Comment: Please show an [MRE] of your solution. It is not so far off after all.

Comment: Take the average of the remaining value for the remaining elements. So here: 1st element is 5/3 = 1. Update x=4, y=2, second element is 4/2 = 2. Update x=2, y=1, last element = 2.

Comment: What does "evenly distribute" mean? If I gave you `x=7, y=5`, is `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` good? Or do you want `[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]`?

Comment: Do you need the lower parts (the "1" in your example) to come first, or is it OK to do the highers first and then the lower?

Comment: @Yunnosch why did you post an answer if you're not certain of the author's intent?

Comment: Because it is so trivial that I can adapt the answer if it is needed. @sche001

Comment: @scohe001 it does not matter. either `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` or `[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]` is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified to only printing the numbers you want.
First print x/y+1 as often as you have remainder (I.e. modulo), then print for the rest of the needed numbers only x/y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
    int i=0;
    
    for (; i < x%y; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", x/y+1);
    }
    for (; i < y; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", x/y);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 2 1
```